# Does SQL server retrieve the same rows when you use top statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL table consists of three columns - Event (type xml), InsertedTime (type datetime) and status (type nvarchar - possible values processed and unprocessed). None of them are unique identifiers and all of these are mandatory.

As part of a select query, I retrieve the top 1000 rows of the table (based on the unprocessed status), use the XML to retrieve some values, and would like to update the status of these exact 1000 rows to processed status.

My question is: I'm using the SELECT TOP 1000 FROM table WHERE status ='Unprocessed' ORDER BY InsertedTime to retrieve and UPDATE TOP 1000 table WHERE status = 'Processed' ORDER BY InsertedTime statements to achieve this.

I understand that in Oracle, I can use the rowid pseudocolumn to ensure that I'm updating the same rows that were retrieved in the first place. But how do I achieve this without having any unique identifier or primary key in the table in SQL?

Note: The table is being written to continuously.

Comment: If multiple rows may have the same `InsertedTime` value then no, it's not guaranteed - `TOP` is only deterministic if you have an `ORDER BY` clause *and* the expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause are sufficient to uniquely determine the order of rows. You don't appear to meet the second requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You're selecting rows to be handled and then trying to update the status of those rows? Instead of doing select + update you could use output clause, with something like this:

```
UPDATE TOP (1000) table 
set status = 'Processed' 
output deleted.Event, deleted.InsertedTime, deleted.status
where status = 'Unprocessed'
```

This will both update the rows + return Event, InsertedTime and status fields (old values). If you need the new values, you can use the virtual table inserted.

Comment: Thanks JamesZ for the response. I understand the above. However, when I retrieve the rows for the first time and use them. Based on the information inside the XML, I would need to set the status as "Failed" or "Processed". Therefore, I feel both the select and update can't go together. Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: In that case you can't use this, or at least you would need to have xml handling in the update. Most likely it's best to add an identity field to the table to be used like rowid in oracle

Comment: Yes, I have now added an identity field with an auto increment on it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that processes may try to insert new rows while your two queries are processing, you have a few options:

1. Wrap the two queries in a transaction. This should guarantee atomicity between them, at the cost of extra locking on the table.
2. Find the oldest `InsertedTime` value from the first query and use that with the `WHERE` clause in the 2nd query.
3. Combine the UPDATE and SELECT into a single statement via an [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.

Comment: Well, with #2, you'd have to somehow deal with ties that could land on the boundary...